# appropriate test for comparison between two variables

Tags: statistical-significance

I have two variables ,  Variable1 and Variable 2.

Variable 1 has three levels { Pizza, Pasta, Breadstick }

Variable 2 has five levels { American, German, Spanish, Japanese, Chinese }

The response distribution is as follows

```
             Pizza       Pasta       Breadstick
  American   2           1           28
  German     0           0           8
  Spanish    0           0           2
  Japanese   1           0           0  
  Chinese    0           1           1
```

We can apply Chi-Square test to compare association between these two variables. However I am not sure about using Chi-Square test when there are a lot of zeros. I am wondering if anybody has any suggestions for any other test that could be applicable here other than Chi-Square test for this scenario with many zeros?

Comment: Not the best answer (see @LambdaPsi for starters), but you should consider combining Spanish, Japanese, and Chinese into an 'other' cell -- that would reduce your number of cells with E[0] rather dramatically. It would also reduce the number of tests you are implicitly performing, thus improving your power somewhat substantially.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right direction. [Chi-square tests are not appropriate when you have small expected values in many cells.](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2011/11/07/chi-square-fail-when-many-cells-have-small-expected-values/)

Instead, you can try a Poisson regression by treating the value in each cell as a count value, and predicting the count variable with dummy-coded Variables 1 and 2.

Comment: How will this help in testing Independence?